# How to register dependencies that are not defined explicitly as Strict using AutoFixture with FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture, fakeiteasy

I use AutoFixture with FakeItEasy when I need to test a class with many dependencies, but I ned to mock only some of them. All the rest of dependencies I prefer mocking with Strict() option of FakeItEasy. In order to make my test more clean, I would like to mock only the dependencies that I want and be able to specify that all the dependencies that do not mock are created with Strict().

In the example below, I would like to be able to remove the two lines of code that create mock of IDependency2, but keep the same behavior: if the class under test accesses any method of IDependency2, an exception would be thrown.

Any idea how to do this?

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutoTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());

        var dependency1 = fixture.Freeze<IDependency1>();
        A.CallTo(() => dependency1.DoSomething()).Returns(12);

        // I do not want to specify these two lines
        var dependency2 = A.Fake<IDependency2>(s=>s.Strict());
        fixture.Register(() => dependency2);

        // Act
        var classUnderTest = fixture.Create<ClassUnderTest>();
        var actualResult = classUnderTest.MethodUnderTest();

        // Assert
        Assert.That(actualResult,Is.GreaterThan(0));
    }
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly IDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IDependency2 _dependency2;

    public ClassUnderTest(IDependency1 dependency1, IDependency2 dependency2)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }

    public int MethodUnderTest()
    {
        return _dependency1.DoSomething() 
            + _dependency2.DoSomething();
    }
}

public interface IDependency1
{
    int DoSomething();
}

public interface IDependency2
{
    int DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want Test Doubles to be strict if you don't care about them?

Comment: I do care that those dependencies are not called by mistake. If they are not faked explicitly and they are used - test should fail.

Comment: Why is it important that they aren't called by mistake? Do these dependencies have side-effects?

Comment: Let me explain. Let's suppose I write a class with two dependencies. I test it in unit tests and it is fine. Then I (or somebody else) adds another dependency and use it in the previously written method. As a result I (or he/she) adds another behavior to the code that was already tested. That addition might fail with an exception, but it is not tested. If the test would fail, it would remind me (or the other person): "hey, I need to take a look at this test and modify it according to this change".

Comment: If I write the test by simply creating the class under test using its constructor, I would be notified by resharper/compiler. But using AutoFixture actually hides the potential damage to the class that was already tested. Maybe I am too paranoid, just trying to understand whether it is possible.

Comment: Hiding the constructor details is [one of the points](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/02/13/SUTFactory) of AutoFixture, because it decouples the unit tests from the constructor, which is rarely the code being tested. If you *do* care about the constructor, why not use that, instead of AutoFixture?

Comment: Ok, I understand that maybe this is not the best practice. But the question remains the same, "is it possible to decorate automatically created mocks with some customization?" Such customization might be Strict or Synchronized or anything else.

Comment: In my opinion, using *Strict* semantic is generally not good idea because it causes tight coupling between API under test and implementation details. However, I think the solution of your problem should be enforcement for you and your team to respect [Open-Close principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Modifying existing classes or unit tests should be considered as potential point of introducing bugs. Rather than creating mechanism for notifications when new dependency is added to existing class, maybe it would be better to create new class which composes the old one.

Comment: Look at this from another angle: When you use *AutoFakeItEasyCustomization* it means that all mocks which you have created from AutoFixture are by default customized, they have established some default behaviour, thus may be treated as configured in the similar way as you could do yourself using explicit FakeItEasy API. Mocks methods can return autogenerated values, and specific unit test may not need to have precisely set-up mock to pass.

Comment: What I can advice you to do after new dependency is added is to split tests which are now failed into a new separated unit tests according to [equivalence class](http://xunitpatterns.com/equivalence%20class.html) related to return values from the new dependency's methods. Afterwards you should review your other test methods to verify if they still describes the real responsibility of your class (to find [false negatives](http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20negative.html) ). Finally, you can write new additional unit tests to cover different behaviours of this new dependency.

Comment: I am very happy, that we are having this conversation. As a big fan of SOLID principles, of course I would accept your suggestion,  @  sgnsajgon . Maybe I am trying to use (or abuse) unit tests as educational tool for my peers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a tradeoff solution, It's quite simple to implement custom **ISpecimenBuilder** to have all autogenerated fakes as *Strict* fakes. You can take a look at standard *[Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy.FakeItEasyRelay](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFakeItEasy/FakeItEasyRelay.cs)* fakes builder to get idea what's going on behind the curtain. The modified custom builder for Strict fakes is implemented as follows:

```
    public class FakeItEasyStrictRelay : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            if (!this.IsSatisfiedBy(request))
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            var type = request as Type;
            if (type == null)
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            var fakeFactoryMethod = this.GetType()
                .GetMethod("CreateStrictFake", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .MakeGenericMethod((Type) request);

            var fake = fakeFactoryMethod.Invoke(this, new object[0]);

            return fake;
        }

        public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
        {
            var t = request as Type;
            return (t != null) && ((t.IsAbstract) || (t.IsInterface));
        }

        private T CreateStrictFake<T>()
        {
            return A.Fake<T>(s => s.Strict());
        }
    }
```

It can be simply register with the following statement:

```
 IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
                new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization( new FakeItEasyStrictRelay()));
```